# Using the ls command on an Ubuntu 14.04.10 server to explore my files

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, ls

Very new to Linux, but I thought I understood file exploration from the command line.

**The problem:**
I can't figure out how to navigate my files or directories, the console isn't displaying any feedback when I type "ls" or "pwd" or "cd".  Example:

```
tyler@ip-172-31-13-165:~$ cd /home/tyler
tyler@ip-172-31-13-165:~$ ls
tyler@ip-172-31-13-165:~$ ls /home/tyler
```

It's not showing me anything!  How do I know what directories exist?

**what I've done so far:**
I have recently created a Ubuntu 14.04.1 micro instance with AWS, which I'll be using to practice webapp deployment. I am connecting to the instance via puTTy on Windows 7.  I created a new user: tyler with sudo privileges, as follows:

**What I want:**
I want some way to explore the files/directories I've created/that have been created for me using the command line (I don't want to rely on a GUI).

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/342438/trying-to-understand-my-first-server-set-up/)

Comment: @Seth hmm, that didn't come up in my search.  I believe my title is more searchable for users in the future who experienced the same problem.  I read his question 3 times and still wasn't sure what he was asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the `ls` command does not work differently on server editions of Ubuntu.

What *does* work differently is that, by default, user creation on the server additions does not include populating the new user's home directory with folders such as `Desktop` (because there isn't one), `Pictures` and so on. So `ls` is simply telling you that there are currently no ordinary (non-hidden) files or directories within your home directory. If you want to see *hidden* files and directories, add the `-A` or `-a` flags e.g.

```
ls -A
```

See `man ls`

```
   -a, --all
          do not ignore entries starting with .

   -A, --almost-all
          do not list implied . and ..
```

Comment: ah!  yeah, there is is.  its amazing how the slightest variation from expected output can make a habitual gui user, like myself, panic.  I'm so used to the immediate feedback from a GUI.  Thanks for your help, I'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there's nothing in that directory?

Try "ls /" which should list contents of root directory.

Comment: that actually did work, thank you.  It's odd to me that they initialized the ubuntu user folder with nothing in it.  still learning.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative, `tree` command gives you more complex information regarding directories in tree view.

Install it with `sudo apt-get install tree`
and try to type `tree /`